# How to disable live reloading in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a Qurkus application which I run in Dev mode:

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

I have an issue that Quarkus reloads classes also when I don't want it to (dependent project updated, etc) which takes quite a lot of time.

**Question:** Is there a way to disable live reloading in dev mode?

I went through the Quarkus documentation, but couldn't find if there is such an option.

Comment: Check this: https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-1-13-1-final-released/#instrumentation-based-live-reload-disabled-by-default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it with Quarkus since `2.0.0.Alpha3` by enabling the corresponding option in the console (Quarkus tells you which key you need to press to do that - it's `l`).

See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/17035 for the pull request that brought this feature